# Why can't I make these buttons draggable using jQueryUI even though I'm using {cancel: false}?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, drag

I'm trying to make buttons draggable and droppable using jQueryUI. I know that in order to do this, I have to set the cancel attribute; however, it doesn't seem to be working in this specific case. My code is [on this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8a7D/289/).

As you can see, I've set the button to alert the html of the button when it's clicked, but having this function doesn't allow me to drag the button anymore. If I remove it, my button can be dragged. If I remove the cancel:false attribute, it (correctly) disables dragging, so I'm not sure why it's not letting me drag when the .on(click) is present.

```
function init() {
$('#makeMeDraggable ul li').draggable({cancel:false});
}

$("#unorderedlist").on('click','li',function(){
alert($(this).html);
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `.on()` wasn't added to jQuery until 1.7 and you're using an older version in your fiddle (along with some typos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looked at your console you'd have noticed that you had a syntax error...

```
$("#unorderedlist").on('click','li',function()
{
    alert($(this).html);
}
```

Should be:

```
$("#unorderedlist").on('click','li',function()
{
    alert($(this).html);
});
```

Also, you were using a very old version of jQuery. I've updated the fiddle to a more recent version

This works now:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8a7D/291/)

So, always run your code with your browser's developer tools (often via F12) open so you can catch errors